# Stripping leading zeros using bash substring removal only

Tags: bash

*I am aware of other ways to solve this problem that do work (and I am currently using the 'expr' method), but it bugs me that I cannot figure out how to do it with the bash built-in functions only.*

When I try to strip the leading zeros from a variable using the ${variable##remove} construct I can either only get it to remove one zero or all numbers.

```
string="00123456"
echo "${string##0}" // Only the first 0 is removed
echo "${string##0*0}" // The whole string is removed
echo "${string#0*0}" // Works

string="01230"
echo "${string##0}" // Works
echo "${string##0*0}" // The whole string is removed
echo "${string#0*0}" // Again, the whole string is removed
```

I read the bash manual twice to see if I am doing it correctly, but the official documentation is sparse at best. I am aware that enabling extglob may also solve this problem but it seems like overkill for a problem as simple as this.

Am I missing something obvious or is it really that hard to remove one or more leading zeros from a string using bash functions only?

Comment: Just for your information, these constructs are not called "bash substring removal". They are ["varieties of parameter expansion"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) and they are specified by posix (which bash mostly implements). HTH.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The following would remove all the leading `0`s from the string:

```
$ string="000123456000"
$ echo "${string#"${string%%[!0]*}"}"
123456000
```

Saying `"${string%%[!0]*}"` would return the match after deleting the longest trailing portion of the string that satisifies `[!0]*` -- essentially returning the zeros at the beginning.

`"${string#"${string%%[!0]*}"}"` would remove the part returned by the above from the beginning of the string.

---

Alternatively, you could use shell arithmetic:

```
$ string="0000123456000"
$ echo $((10#$string))
123456000
```

Comment: +1 Could you elaborate on how it works? It's seems to be an awesome solution but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: @helpermethod Added an explanation.

Comment: That appears to be the one. Still, my mind keeps shouting at me that there should be a way without a 'double-negative'. I too would like to know more about why this works, where all single statements fail.

Comment: The first solution is appealing, but hard to remember. Here's a function wrapper (works with multiple inputs): `stripLeadingZeros() { local s; for s in "$@"; do printf '%s\n' "${s#"${s%%[!0]*}"}"; done; }`.

Comment: From 11123717: The $(()) sets up an arithmetic context and the 10# converts the number from base 10 to base 10 causing any leading zeros to be dropped.

Answer (score 9):

Working with minutes and hours in a cron job generator script I found that leading zeros in front of 08 & 09 cause bash to think the value is an invalid octal amount. The script could not just strip leading zeros because a single zero is still valid. The solution was to pipe to bc.

```
HOUR=09
echo $HOUR | bc
9

HOUR=0
echo $HOUR | bc
0

HOUR=14
echo $HOUR | bc
14
```

Answer (score 8):

Yet another way, although this requires the extglob functionality being enabled:

```
echo ${string/#+(0)/}
```

Comment: It is for the `+()` syntax... At least in `bash` 3.2.x. Defaults might have changed in newer versions, I guess. As the other answers indicate, though, there are other ways to do it without relying on extglob...

Comment: The release notes for bash *4.1* say "There is a new confgure option that forces the extglob option to be enabled by default." - http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/NEWS.
Not sure what "configure option" refers to, but a quick test on two bash 4.2 systems tells me that `extglob` is ON by default there. As you say, it's OFF by default on 3.2.x, which applies to OS X to this day (OS X 10.9).
The bottom line: to be safe across multiple bash versions, you need to make sure the option is turned on, which makes this otherwise handy solution less desirable.

Comment: @mklement0 ... Unless you're in the habit of making sure it's always on anyway (.profile/.bashrc)...

Comment: That's great if you know your scripts will only run in an environment that YOU control; if portability is a requirement, you must take the extra step of ensuring that `extglob` is on (and, preferably, if you had to turn it on, turn it off again afterwards). These global options are what makes writing portable shell scripts tricky.

Comment: For completeness, the answer should state how this feature is enabled in the shell.

Answer (score 5):

This is also a pure BASH way of stripping leading zeroes in an one-liner:

```
string="00123456"
[[ "$string" =~ ^0*(.+)$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
123456
```

Note: regexp covers the edge case of "00000" input to be turned into just "0".

Comment: I like it: +1...  but I don't see the need for `&&` -- the `[[ ... ]]` expression is bullet-proof; it will always result in `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` holding the correct value. Isn't a `;` enough, or am I missing something, here.

Comment: Thanks, I guess performance wise `;` will behave same as `&&`

Comment: ps. Also, This method can easily allow for a single remaining `0` - which is what I was hunting for - `echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]:-0}`. – (Of course that can be done with the other answers, but would require another var assignment step).

Comment: Yes, certainly. your answer addresses the question, but for my particular requirement, I want to leave just `0` if the string was `000`.  (by the way, it is slower than the others, but it works, and has shown an interesting use of BASH_REMATCH - they certainly weren't golfing with that name :)

Answer (score 5):

Delete the longest substring from the beginning of the string matching the extended glob pattern `+(0)`, that is, one or more zeros.

```
shopt -s extglob
string="0000123456000"
echo ${string##+(0)}
```

*prints:*

```
123456000
```

Note: this will reduce a string containing only zeros to an empty string.

```
shopt -s extglob
string="0000000000000"
echo ${string##+(0)}
```

*prints an empty string.*

If you want a string of zeros to reduce to a single zero, you can use arithmetic expansion together with the *[base#]n* form to force an arithmetic base of 10 to prevent octal interpretation:

```
string="0000000000000"
echo $((10#$string))
```

*prints:*

```
0
```